# CSS stripped upon exiting DIVI Visual Builder

Tags: css, divi

Upon exiting Divi Visual Builder, my CSS is stripped from my site.

I have gone into advanced options and disabled static CSS file generation as per other solutions I came across, however, still my CSS is stripped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where are you putting the CSS? There are several places Divi allows you to add custom CSS. Also, you might want to talk to the Elegant Themes support team.

Comment: Divi support center is a better place to ask this.

Comment: @disinfor I've added the CSS to the Custom Css section in the Divi advanced theme options.

Comment: @m4n0 is there a DIvi support center on Stack overflow?

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/members-area/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elegantthemes.com%2Fmembers-area%2Fhelp%2F